# Laravel Foreign Key Guarded or Fillable

Tags: php, laravel, rest, laravel-5

I am trying to develop a Restful API with Laravel 5 and i have a table as below

```
Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('company_name');
    $table->string('direction');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The field `user_id` is a foreign key and i want to create a new `Report` record when make a POST request via Android App.

My question is, what should be the status of `user_id` field ? Guarded or fillable ?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

you should set it to fillable, because you want to set this value on model creation.

For more details see the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: My only concern is, making it fillable might cause a security issue. What do you think about that ?

Comment: if you do something like $report = new Report(Input::all()); then there could be an issue. In this case a guarded attribute might be the right thing. It comes down to how you want to create and update your models.

Comment: This article could help clarify http://hndr.me/blog/laravel-mass-assignment-protection-blacklist-vs-whitelist/

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I'd suggest to rethink that strategy, however, here's something you can try if you really need to do it that way.

Don't add  user_id's to either `$fillable` or `$guarded`. Set up a [model observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-observers) and assign the id right there.

That way you can pass the call safely to the Report model and still be able to hook into the process of creating/reading the Report/User